# Override the custom field rendering in a list view

Tags: custom-field-types

When creating a custom field in SharePoint 2010, what method do I need to override to control what is rendered for the custom field type in the list where it is used?

I tried overriding `GetFieldValue` to no effect.

Comment: I have the same problem but using sharepoint services 3.0
who can help me, I need run querys in custum fields when the list view or load.
I dont know how run a custom handler for list event. tks.
JosePa.

Answer (score 4):

@Marek is right in his assertion that you should use XSLT. However, in 2010 (only) there are functions you can override to alter a field's output:

- [GetFieldValueAsText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.getfieldvalueastext.aspx) is used by most field types for rendering
- [GetFieldValueAsHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.getfieldvalueashtml.aspx) is used by Note fields and similar

Each of these accepts an `Object value` input, which is either the raw data directly from the list, or the output from the `<RenderPattern Name="DisplayPattern">` in the fldTypes...xml (if you're using `<Field Name="CAMLRendering">TRUE</Field>`).

The output from whichever of these functions is used is then pushed through the XSLT (if you've provided any) and rendered.

I haven't seen any examples of this method being used in the wild, however (we don't use it due to 2007 incompatibility) so I'd advise caution.

Comment: Unless I've missed something, these aren't actually called when rendering to a regular list view.

Comment: @Rawling: I'm guessing you're using 2007, or possibly a 2007 site migrated to 2010?

Comment: Nope, 2010 here. I don't -think- I've missed anything in my implementation - my constructors and `BaseFieldControl` overrides get hit - but these methods jsut don't get called.

Comment: Could be to do with your field type. Which SPField derivative are you inheriting from?

Comment: I'm inheriting `SPMultiLineText` - I'm trying to make a Markdown column :) I've got it rendering properly in item Display forms via a custom rendering control which _calls_ `GetFieldValueAsHTML` but not in the list.

Comment: How odd. Does it have a ParentType of Note in the fldtypes.XML?

Comment: Yes, and the rendering control inherits from `NoteField`.

Comment: Let's [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4524/discussion-between-stuart-pegg-and-rawling)

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint 2010 renders fields on a list view is with **XSLT style sheets**, so there is no method to override. If you want a your own way of rendering on list views, you need to create a custom XSLT style sheet named `fldtypes_*.xsl` and deployed it to `(14 hive)\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\XSL`.

- [How to: Create a Custom Field Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862248.aspx) (paragraph *3. (Optional) Create a Custom XSLT Style Sheet*)
- [How to: Customize the Rendering of a Field on a List View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff606773.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

A field type's rendering can be controller by binding it to a BaseFieldControl derived custom control:

https://www.chakkaradeep.com/2008/12/15/sharepoint-creating-a-custom-field/

Comment: I took "in the list" to mean "in the List View". Looks like we've covered both bases between us. :)

Comment: This link is dead. Editing answer to provide new link.